# How can I log the number of a specific DOM element into the console?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm trying to log the number of elements in a html document that have the `id` "para" here is the code so far

```
window.addEventListener("load",init);
function init(){

        var b = document.getElementById("para");

        console.log(b);

}
```

so far it will only log the element itself and not the number of them in the html document

Comment: More than one element with the same id in HTML is invalid markup. You can give elements the same name though.

Comment: You should use classes for multiple elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   var b = document.getElementById("para");
```

Note the singular in this class, it only returns a single element (or null).

If your document is well-formed, there will only be ONE element with the ID of `para`.  That is one of the things that separates IDs from classes.

You have two solutions.

- Get away from using ID and use either class or data-* attributes
- use `document.querySelectorAll("#para")`

Of the two, I recommend fixing your HTML.

**Demo code in reference to a comment**

```js
var list = document.querySelectorAll("#test-span");
console.log(list.length);
```

```html
<span id="test-span">1</span>
<span id="test-span">1</span>
<span id="test-span">1</span>
```

Comment: I'll bet `querySelectorAll` won't do what he wants, either.

Comment: @Barmar See the included example.  It does what the OP has asked for.